# Diagnosing libssh2 SFTP blocking call

Tags: c++, sftp, libssh, libssh2

I'm using the most recent Git tree of libssh2 to perform some SFTP work.  I'm using the non-blocking interface.

I'm successful in establishing a connection to the SFTP server, logging in, and transferring files.

However, I'm encountering a problem where the call to `libssh2_sftp_write(sftp_handle, ptr, nread)` plain hangs.  This **always** happens after 237115172 bytes of data are transferred.
While the payload is smaller than this number, things proceed just fine.

I'm transferring multiple files.  I'm using a single SSH session (and a single socket) for the entire transaction.  Can anyone suggest a direction for solving this problem?  The magic number 237115172 is a hint, but it doesn't make any sense to me just yet.  What could I be doing wrong?

This is the code, straight out of the libssh2 examples:

```
do 
{
    nread = fread(m_buffer, 1, sizeof(m_buffer), local);
    //
    // EOF
    //
    if (nread <= 0) 
        break;
    ptr = m_buffer;
    total += nread;
    do 
    {
        //
        // FIXME: this hangs sometimes... why?!
        //

        /* write data in a loop until we block */
        while 
        (
            (rc = libssh2_sftp_write(sftp_handle, ptr, nread)) 
            == 
            LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN
        ) 
        {
            if (m_aborted)
                goto cleanup;
            waitsocket(m_sock, m_session);
        }
        if (rc < 0)
            break;
        ptr += rc;
        nread -= rc;
        m_uploadedBytes += rc;
        emit totalUploadChanged(100*(float)m_uploadedBytes/m_totalBytes);
    } 
    while (nread);
} 
while (rc > 0);
```

I can post the full source, but it's quite long, and since it's part of a QT app it would take a bit of effort to rip out.

Comment: @John Zwinck: It's defined as `char m_buffer[1024*100];`

Comment: Try making it 25K, just on a lark.  I once had a weird problem with libssh2 which only occurred when my buffer was 32 KB or larger.  I don't know the exact reason why (I found some hints back then which I have since forgotten), but it was some kind of bug in the library.  I changed my buffer to 31KB and it worked forever after.

Comment: @John Zwinck: thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it still hangs.  However, this always happens when the number of transferred bytes is 147671992.  I'll look at the relationship between the two numbers later.

Comment: You might try using Wireshark to visualize what's happening on the network....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I had two versions of libssh2 installed: 1.2.2. in /usr and 1.3.0 (from the git repository) in /usr/local.  I didn't have any attachment to a particular version, so I removed the more recent one (the older one was a dependency for other software on my machine).

I had to make two or three small changes to adapt to the older interface, but at least the problem described in the original question went away.

Comment: Note that version 1.2.2 is two years and 8 versions out of date. Try version 1.3.0 and see if that works any better. Note that there is no version 1.5 of libssh2.

Comment: @Dan: my bad, the version was 1.3.0 out of the Git repo.  I've amended my post.